# Is there a more efficient way to calculate complex vector rotation?

Tags: complex-numbers, vectors, rotations

My textbook(Year 12 Cambridge Extension 2) asked me this question:
[image]

For question (b), is there a more simple way of answering this question than this:

[image: My solution]

It really isn't that big but, I would expect something less cumbersome for question 4 in the exercise and I feel I may be not seeing an extremely simple solution. Thanks to anyone who can help :)

Comment: Since it's a square, we can represent $C=iA$ as a $90$ degree rotation and $B=A+C$ like you would by vectors. You can represent a rotation by $45$ degrees as multiplication by $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$. So multiply that by $B$ to get your answer.

Comment: @Merosity Yeah, ok. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have learned Euler’s formula $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta + i\sin\theta$, then there is a more general theorem:

multiply a complex number $z$ with $e^{i\theta}$, you will get the point rotated $\theta$ in radians counterclockwise.

[image]

And when you replace the $\theta$ here with $45^\circ$, or $\frac\pi 4$, you will get the number $\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$.

The proof of this theorem is given by the sum of angle identity of $\sin$ and $\cos$. If originally $z$ has a magnitude of $r$ and angle $\phi$ with the $x$-axis, then:

$$
\begin{align*}
z_2 &= z_1e^{i\theta} \\
&= (r\cos(\phi)+r\sin(\phi)i)(\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)i) \\
&= r\cdot[(\cos(\phi)\cos(\theta)-\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)) - (\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta)+\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta))i] \\
&= r\cos(\theta+\phi) + r\sin(\theta+\phi)i,
\end{align*}
$$

which represents the complex number with magnitude $r$ and angle $(\theta+\phi)$ between the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Rotating anticlockwise by $90^\circ$ in the complex plane can by done by multiplying by $i$. $B=A+C$. The angle $\widehat{BOC}=45^\circ$ so $B'$ is in the direction of $C$ but $\sqrt{2}$ times longer.

$C=(2+i)i=2i+i^2=-1+2i$

$B=A+C=(2+i)+(-1+2i)=1+3i$

$B'=C\sqrt{2}=(-1+2i)\sqrt{2}=-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}i$

I should think you're expected to do both parts with complex numbers rather than plane geometry, though. This is only slightly more complicated. We need to know that rotating anticlockwise by $45^\circ$ can be done by multiplying by $(1+i)/\sqrt{2}$.

$B'=(1+3i)(1+i)/\sqrt{2}=(1+i+3i+3i^2)/\sqrt{2}=(-2+4i)/\sqrt{2}=-\sqrt{2}+2\sqrt{2}i$